# Aldryn article meta options not appearing in webpage page source

Tags: django, django-cms, divio

I am using Aldryn Newsblog for article management on a website built on Django CMS.

Aldryn allows us to add meta options to each article, please refer to [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLSWg.jpg).

My inputs for **meta title** and **meta description** are not showing in the webpage page source.

Will like to seek help for this please, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The `{% page_attribute %}` tag is used by the cms to render the page's meta and other properties.
This tag will not work for newsblog articles as they are a different object.

I suggest to wrap the `{% page_attribute "meta_description" %}` call in a block on your page base template:

```
{% block meta %}
    <meta name="description" content="{% page_attribute 'meta_description' %}">
{% endblock meta%}
```

Then in your article base template you can do something like:

```
{% block meta %}
    {% if article %}
        {# rendering article detail page #}
        <meta name="description" content="{{ article.meta_description }}">
    {% else %}
        {# rendering article landing page #}
        {{ block.super }}
    {% endif %}
{% endblock meta%}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have these lines inside `<head>...</head>` of your `base.html`?

```
{% page_attribute "page_title" as title %}
<title>{{ title }}</title>
```

and

```
<meta name="description" content="{% page_attribute "meta_description" %}">
```

Comment: Thanks Marcelo. Yes I do have both pieces of code.  The meta information currently reflects that set for my aldryn newsblog section (attached below is a link to describe what is a section).  I will like the meta information to reflect that set for the article instead.   http://aldryn-newsblog.readthedocs.io/en/latest/how-to/apphook_configurations.html